# верстка элемента css

Tags: html, css, css3

Как сделать , чтобы было как на картинках, мобильная версия и десктопе, что-то не могу подогнать под мобильную версию, да и десктопная не очень

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.slider-index-bg {
  background-position: right top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  background-size: 90%;
  background-image: url(http://vodprava.com/assets/img/bluebg.png); }

.data-slider .item .inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; }

.data-slider .item .data-slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: auto auto;
          background-size: auto;
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-align-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-line-pack: justify;
          align-content: space-between;
  background-image: url(http://vodprava.com/assets/img/car.png); }
  .data-slider .item .data-slide .container .box-inner {
    padding: 5% 0 25%;
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
        -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
            align-content: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
        -ms-flex-pack: start;
            justify-content: flex-start; }
  .data-slider .item .data-slide .data-info {
    max-width: 540px; }
    .data-slider .item .data-slide .data-info h1 {
      color: #6f6f6f;
      font-size: 36px;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-transform: uppercase; }
      .data-slider .item .data-slide .data-info h1 span {
        display: block;
        margin: 60px 0;
        font-size: 60px;
        font-weight: 800;
        line-height: 60px; }
    .data-slider .item .data-slide .data-info .btn-down {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex; }

.step {
  padding: 0 0 70px; }
  .step .title {
    color: #6f6f6f;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
  .step .step-box {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 100%;
        -ms-flex: 0 1 100%;
            flex: 0 1 100%;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
        -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
            align-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
        -ms-flex-align: start;
            align-items: flex-start; }
    .step .step-box .item {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
          -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
              flex-wrap: wrap;
      -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
          -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
              align-content: flex-start;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
          -ms-flex-pack: center;
              justify-content: center;
      justify-items: center;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0 15px; }
      .step .step-box .item .icon {
        position: relative;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        width: 135px;
        height: 135px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
                border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-align-content: center;
            -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
                align-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
                justify-content: center;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #058afe, #5cd8ef);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #058afe, #5cd8ef);
        background: linear-gradient(45deg, #058afe, #5cd8ef); }
        .step .step-box .item .icon:after {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
                  border-radius: 50%;
          top: 10px;
          left: -10px;
          right: 10px;
          bottom: -10px;
          background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #058afe, #5cd8ef);
          background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #058afe, #5cd8ef);
          background: linear-gradient(45deg, #058afe, #5cd8ef);
          opacity: 0.2; }
      .step .step-box .item h4 {
        max-width: 100%;
        -webkit-flex-basis: 100%;
            -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
                flex-basis: 100%;
        color: #6f6f6f;
        font-weight: 800;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 20px; }
      .step .step-box .item p {
        line-height: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #6f6f6f; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="data-slider slider-index-bg">
   <div class="item">
    <div class="inner">
     <div class="data-slide">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="box-inner">
        <div class="data-info">
         <h1>Помощь в получении
          <span>
           водительского
           удостоверения
          </span>
         </h1>
         <a href="" class="btn-blue">Ознакомиться</a>
         <span class="btn-down">12</span>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step-p">
     <div class="container">
   <div class="step">
    <p class="title">поступательные действия</p>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="step-box">
      <div class="item">
       <div class="icon">
        <img src="img/step1.png" alt="">
       </div>
       <h4>заполнение анкеты</h4>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <div class="icon">
        <img src="img/step1.png" alt="">
       </div>
       <h4>название этапа №2</h4>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <div class="icon">
        <img src="img/step3.png" alt="">
       </div>
       <h4>получение водительского удостоверения</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. </p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тебе скорее всего дали макет. Кроме макета дали условия как сверстать. Раз у тебя есть макет/ы, то в них указаны размеры и детали.

Comment: дело в том, как расположить эти картинки по блокам

Comment: какие картинки расположить не получается ?

Comment: которые сейчас в вопросе согласно макету